# Not dot equivalent

Tags: symbols, amssymb, amsfonts

I found `\doteq` and `\neq`/`\ne` but i am searching for a combination of those two.
Something like `\dotneq` or `\dotne`, which both don't seem to work.

I can use `\dot{\ne}` but that puts the dot way up.

I also tried drawing it at [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), but had no luck.

Comment: Welcome! Did you try `\not\doteq`?

Comment: No, didn't try, but this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt should always be prefixing the relation symbol with `\not` and see what happens. In this case you get, from `\not\doteq`,

[image]

which may or may not be what you're looking for. The main condition for `\not` to work is that the symbol to be negated is as wide as the equals sign, because `\not` is defined to be a relation symbol that sticks outside of its (zero-width) bounding box so that the middle point of the bar is horizontally midway of the equals sign.

It doesn't always work (this is font dependent, though). For instance, `\not\mid` or `\not\in` yield disputable results

[image]

The former is grossly wrong, the latter has the diagonal bar too near the end of the symbol. Sometimes we find `\not|` for correcting the former, but

[image]

is likewise bad. A possible fix could be `\not|\mathrel{}`

[image]

but `amssymb` provides `\nmid` and the LaTeX kernel provides `\notin`

[image]

Look in the documentation for your font packages for other special negated symbols.

Comment: I approve you beautiful method. :-) and it's already 2021 in a few hours and I'm getting older and older :-( how sad.

Answer (score 0):

`MnSymbol` (or `fdsymbol`) package has also the specific `\ndoteq` symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
$ab \ndoteq cd \sim dc$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This changes *all* symbols, using ones specially tailored to go with Minion, which is a rather peculiar font.

Comment: @egreg Dear I am conscious that the packages I have indicated change the whole scheme and the classic standard symbols. I simply wanted to inform you that there are these packages with the specific command. I think that this symbol can be extracted only from the corresponding slot. I thank you infinitely always.